# How to check if all boolean are true or false in Java?

Tags: java, operators

I'm trying to figure out how to check if three variables are all true or all false. So that the condition becomes true, when these variables have the same value and false, when they don't have the same value.
I thought something like `(d == e == f)` would help me here but the condition is only true when all variables are set to true. But when they're set to false, the condition doesn't work. Could anyone explain to me why? I know a very basic issue but I really can't figure it out myself.

Comment: `false == false == false` -> `(false == false) == false` -> `true == false` -> `false`.

Answer (score 6):

You can try like this :

```
if((d && e && f) || (!d && !e && !f))
```

It will enter in loop either all will be true or all will be false.

Comment: Thanks! Worked great!

Answer (score 3):

It's because all expressions having relational operators return Boolean value.

So, first e == f is evaluated. As these both are false (both operators having same value) so, this expression return true value.
This true value is evaluated against d which is false. So that expression returns false (as both Operators have different values now) .

Comment: OH,... yeah that makes sense. Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: good ways to solve n booleans when you want to check if all are true or all false

Answer (score 1):

To know if the 3 variables are all true or all false; this what you can do:

```
boolean allTrue, allFalse;

if(a && b && c) allTrue = true;  //a, b & c will evaluate to boolean and if all three vars are true the condition will be true and hence the if statement will be accessed
if(!a && !b && !c) allFalse = true; //if the not of the 3 is true, i.e (the 3 boolean vars are false), the whole condtion will be true and the if-statement will be accessed and the allFalse will be set to true means all 3 are false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean allTrue=false;
boolean allFalse=false;

boolean a,b,c;//your three variables
if(a && b && c)
{allTrue=true;}
else if(!a && !b && !c)
 {allFalse=true;}
```

Try this, here i have two variable flags that are set to false initially, when one of the condition is true then only it woll be set to true so after the last line of code you can check if allFalse or allTrue  has values true or false.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to stay closer to the original formulation like this:

```java
boolean eitherAllTrueOrAllFalse = (d == e) && (d == f)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only need to know if all are true or all false, then this will be more than enough:

```
boolean flagAllTrue = a && b && c;
```

No need to use a **if else**.

Comment: Not correct pal, because if a is false and all the others are true this will be false; and this is not the case he asked for

Answer (score -1):

First think of the conditions separately:

```
boolean allTrue = a && b && c;
boolean allFalse = !(a||b||c);
```

Then combine them:

```
boolean eitherAllTrueOrAllFalse = allTrue|allFalse;
```

Comment: Please explain the down vote... divide et impera is good advice even on trivial issues.

Comment: If a is true, then b and c are not evaluated for `allFalse`. The correct expression is:

`boolean allFalse = !a && !b && !c;`

Comment: You do know that !(a||b||c) == !a && !b && !c and also evaluation shortcuts as the first value evaluating to true shortens / aborts evaluation.

Answer (score -1):

```
let sum = 0;

sum += a ? 1:0; sum += b ? 1:0; sum += c ? 1:0;

let allTrueOrAllFalse = ( sum === 0 || sum === 3 );
```